# html dynamically weather data insert to mysql with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this dynamic link.

Every 10 minutes refresh new data from weather station.

I want to sent this data in mysql using php or javascript.

The html link have follow result:

```html
imerominia="26/08/16";
ora="20:22";
sunriseTime=" 06:48";
sunsetTime="20:08";
ForecastStr=" Increasing clouds with little temperature change. Precipitation possible within 24 to 48 hrs.";
tempUnit="°C";
outsideTemp="27.3";
hiOutsideTemp="31.6";
hiOutsideTempAT="18:01";
lowOutsideTemp="20.8";
lowOutsideTempAT="00:32";
hiMonthlyOutsideTemp="36.7";
lowMonthlyOutsideTemp="13.4";
hiYearlyOutsideTemp="38.6";
lowYearlyOutsideTemp="-8.9";
humUnit="% ";
outsideHumidity="39";
hiHumidity="78";
hiHumidityAT=" 00:31";
lowHumidity="32";
lowHumidityAT="12:02";
hiMonthlyHumidity="94";
lowMonthlyHumidity="27";
hiYearlyHumidity="98";
lowYearlyHumidity="20";
outsideDewPt="12.2";
hiDewpoint="17.2";
hiDewpointAT="00:37";
lowDewpoint="10.6";
lowDewpointAT="05:44";
hiMonthlyDewpoint="22.8";
lowMonthlyDewpoint="10.0";
hiYearlyDewpoint="25.0";
lowYearlyDewpoint="-12.2";
windUnit="km/hr";
windSpeed="11.3";
wind10Avg="4.8";
hiWindSpeed="25.7";
hiWindSpeedAT="06:04";
hiMonthlyWindSpeed="53.1";
hiYearlyWindSpeed="61.2";
windDirection="EbS";
moires="96°";
windChill="27.3";
lowWindchill="20.6";
lowWindchillAT="00:32";
lowMonthlyWindchill="13.3";
lowYearlyWindchill="-9.4";
outsideHeatIndex="27.3";
hiHeatindex="31.7";
hiHeatindexAT="18:11";
hiMonthlyHeatindex="42.2";
hiYearlyHeatindex="45.0";
barUnit="hPa";
barometer="1016.7";
BarTrend="Rising Slowly";
hiBarometer="1019.3";
hiBarometerAT=" 09:07";
lowBarometer="1015.6";
lowBarometerAT=" 17:19";
lowMonthlyBarometer="1007.2";
hiMonthlyBarometer="1023.5";
lowYearlyBarometer="993.7";
hiYearlyBarometer="1037.6";
rainUnit="mm";
dailyRain="0.0";
stormRain="0.0";
monthlyRain="16.0";
totalRain="307.6";
rateUnit="mm/hr";
rainRate="0.0";
hiRainRate="0.0";
hiRainRateAT=" n/a";
hiMonthlyRainRate="36.6";
hiYearlyRainRate="1645.8";
solarUnit="W/m²";
solarRad="n/a";
hiSolarRad="0";
hiSolarRadAT="n/a";
hiMonthlySolarRad="0";
hiYearlySolarRad="0";
uvUnit="index";
uv="0.0";
hiUV="0.0";
hiUVAT="n/a";
hiMonthlyUV="0.0";
hiYearlyUV="0.0";
```

I try some tricks but I can't find the solution.

How can this data insert to mysql database auto every 10 minutes or 1 hour or ... etc?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what you've done and ask questions if you have them

Comment: I know to use the language php to create tables rows connect and all basic to mysql (mysqli).
no I wrote the question not to tire you.
My question is essentially this: could the data from this link let 's say an example outsideTemp = "27.3"; send 27.3 in the database table NEW_YORK_WEATHER_STATION in NAME outsideTemp

if these data had in json format, I know how that can convey in a data base .

here in principle we do not know the form of the data , is text form within a html ;